# What will be the research methodology if you are developing a generic software

Tags: research-process, software, methodology, software-papers

I'm developing a generic software for the unorganised retail sector. The design is completely based on the literature review that has been conducted. The only problem is that since I'm not doing any interviews or surveys, what research methodology should I follow ? It can't be qualitative or quantitative. The end result is just the developed software. 
The aim is to study why the unorganised retail is behind than the organised one. And the solution is to present a software for them to use to help in decision making. It's completely based on literature and no surveys or interviews were conducted.

Comment: Probably lacking context. Why do you need a research methodology for developing software? That being said, there's the [design science methodology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_science_(methodology)), which might be relevant for your purpose

Comment: Sounds like a good question for your instructor, alongside with "should I maybe do some interviews or surveys?".

Comment: @lighthouse keeper I'm doing this as a part of my dissertation. And I need to follow a specific methodology to design the software based on the literature review as I can't test the software in real time.

Comment: You need to ask your dissertation advisor  this question.

Comment: OK, that should probably be edited into in the question then. I gave you a pointer to a methodology above.

Comment: This is probably off-topic for academia, but my initial reaction is "what research are you doing?". Writing software is not research, although using it for something may be. By analogy, making a telescope is not research, but using it for something might be (and that thing might be "testing a better telescope design" - similarly for software, if you're a computer scientist). So figure out what the research aspect of your project is, and you'll be part way to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Writing software isn't research. Proving that a piece of software, written by yourself or others, can be research. How are you going to show that your software does what it set out to do? How are you going to show that it is better than the alternatives? For those questions you need methodology. Questionnaires? Observations? Objective measurements? Something.

But the software itself is just a tool. Showing it is valuable is the research part.

And, of course, if it is real research then you need to be prepared for the situation that you get evidence that the new tool isn't actually better. Research is a search for truth, not proof of a predefined statement.